# Layers disappear after a while?

Tags: wordpress, revolution-slider

So I'm using Revolution Slider with 1 slide only and the layers on my slide keep disappearing after X minutes even though:

- my slide is set to 9 seconds
- the slide is set to end on this slide (General Settings -> Pause Slider -> Stop Slider Progress)
- all the layers are [set to fade **after** the slide ends](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WEmR.jpg) so I have no clue what is with this glitch of layers disappearing after a few minutes.

Has anyone experienced something similar?

Answer (score -1):

I reckon your problem will be fixed by following the instructions at https://www.themepunch.com/faq/prevent-layers-from-disappearing/.

To paraphrase those instructions, in the layers timeline section of the slide editor, set the layer to snap to the end of the timeline. The alternative is to set the layer to disappear beforehand which you don't want. This is a simple toggle button under the 'Fade' Column header.